# Bootstrap, nav-stacked not actually stacking list entries

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, nav, nav-pills

It seems I'm missing something obvious here

I expected the `home blog contact` entries to be stacked on top of one another at all times.

What am I missing?

This is what's actually rendering:

[image: This is whats actually rendering]

```html
<body class="body" style="background-color:#f6f6f6">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="min-height:95%; ">
        <hr>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
          <br>

          <br>
           <!-- Great, til you resize. -->
            <!--<div class="well bs-sidebar affix" id="sidebar" style="background-color:#fff">-->
            <div class="well bs-sidebar" id="sidebar" style="background-color:#fff">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href='/blog/'>Blog</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href='/contact/'>Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div> <!--well bs-sidebar affix-->
          </div> <!--col-sm-2-->
          <div class="col-sm-10">

            <div class='container-fluid'>
            <br><br>
               {% block content %}
               {% endblock %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container-fluid" style='margin-left:15px'>
            <p><a href="#" target="blank">Contact</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">LinkedIn</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">Twitter</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">Google+</a></p>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the version of Bootstrap you are using.

Comment: Using bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `well` class in Bootstrap 4. The `card` class can be used instead.

Here's a code snippet that does pretty much what you'd expect:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid" style="min-height:90vh; ">
    <hr>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            <br>

            <br>
            <!-- There's no "well" class in Bootstrap 4. The "card" class can be used instead. -->
            <div class="card bs-sidebar" id="sidebar" style="background-color:#fff">
                <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column flex-sm-row2">
                    <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                    <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                    <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </nav>
            </div> <!--bs-sidebar-->
        </div> <!--col-sm-3 col-md-2-->
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 ">

            <div class='container-fluid'>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <br><br>
                        {% block content %}
                        {% endblock %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p><a href="#" target="blank">Contact</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">LinkedIn</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">Twitter</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">Google+</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#panels-thumbnails-and-wells

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#working-with-flex-utilities

Comment: ah i see, that makes sense. Thank you